# How do you manually update the stock of a product?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have created a field that inherits from saler.order_line that is called packaging (I count the container as a product that is in the warehouse) but at the time of creating the purchase order it is added in the same line as the product I am trying to the package is deducted from the stock but I can not get it. I have tried overwriting the write method but it fails me. Any ideas ?

Sorry for my bad english.

Best regards, Jose Antonio.

Comment: Are you trying to update the quantity of a product? There is a button for this 'Update Qty on Hand' in the product's view

Comment: I'm trying to subtract from the stock when a sale is made

Comment: Can you show us your code where you try to override the write method ?

Answer (score -1):

I have added a product that would act as a container in the same line of order and I want to get in the movement of stock.

[modified sale form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHiby.png)

```
 def action_button_confirm(self, context=None):
    zero_price = [x.product_id.name for x in self.order_line]
    zero_env1 = [x.tipo_env_1.name for x in self.order_line]
    context = dict(context or {})
    procurement_obj = self.pool.get('procurement.order')
    sale_line_obj = self.pool.get('sale.order.line')
    res = {}
    Move = self.env['stock.move']
    warehouse = self.env['stock.warehouse']

    item = self.quant_move_item_model.new({'quant': self.quant1.id})
    item.onchange_quant()
    self.assertEquals(item.source_loc, self.quant1.location_id)


    for transfer in self.order_line:
        moves = self.env['stock.move']
        stock_location = self.env['stock.quant'].search([('product_id', '=', transfer.tipo_env_1.id)])
        move = Move.create({
                    'name': transfer.tipo_env_1.name,
                    'product_id': transfer.tipo_env_1.id,
                    'restrict_lot_id': False,
                    'product_uom_qty':transfer.cantidad_1,
                    'product_uom': 1, #TODO: Change the test value 1 to produc_uom
                    'partner_id': 1, #TODO: Change the test value 1 to partner_id
                    'location_id': stock_location.id,
                    'location_dest_id': 1,                          
            })
    return super(sale_order,self).action_button_confirm()
```